# Map one dataframe to another depending on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, depending on which column of df1 a value from df2 occurs, a value from df2 has to be copied to another specific column of df1.

I tried looping through the dataframe, but it takes ages due to the amount of data. I'm sure there must be some "pandaic" way of doing this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'A': ['X1', 'Y1'],
        'B': ['X2', 'Y2'],
        'A1': ['NaN','NaN'],
        'B1': ['NaN','NaN'],
        }

data2 = {'AB': ['X1', 'Y2', 'X2','Y1'],
        'D': ['D1', 'D4', 'D3', 'D2'],
        }
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['A','B','A1','B1'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['AB','D'])
```

If a value of df1 column A is found in df2, the corresponding value for D has to be copied to column A1. If a value of df1 column B is found in df2, the value of D has to be copied to B1 etc...

It is possible that either a value in A/B is NaN or that there is no corresponding value in df2.

```
data1_goal = {'A': ['X1', 'Y1'],
        'B': ['X2', 'Y2'],
        'A1': ['D1', 'D2'],
        'B1': ['D3', 'D4'],
        }
df_goal=pd.DataFrame(data1_goal, columns=['A','B','A1','B1'])
```

is there an elegant way of doing this beside iterating through df1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='AB').merge(
     df1.merge(df2, left_on='B', right_on='AB'), 
     on=['A','B'])[['A', 'B', 'D_x','D_y']].rename(
     columns={'D_x': 'A1','D_y':'B1'})
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. In my real application I have four columns though, which would make the code quite messy using these sequential merges I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here one way:

```
m=df1.loc[:,['A','B']].melt().merge(df2,left_on='value',right_on='AB').drop('AB',1)
n=m.assign(k=m.groupby('variable').cumcount()).set_index(['variable','k']).unstack(0)
df1=df1.mask(df1.eq('NaN'),n.values) #df1.mask(df1.isna(),n.values) if actual NaN
print(df1)
```

---

```
    A   B  A1  B1
0  X1  X2  D1  D3
1  Y1  Y2  D2  D4
```

Comment: Thank you too. I'm trying to understand your approach and I think I'm getting it but I'm not quite sure what the cumcount() is doing.

Comment: @Maccaroni123 try printing `m.groupby('variable').cumcount()` , this assigns a count to each group, example `A,A` gets `0,1` , again `B,B` gets `0,1`

Comment: I see, and every category A,B.. should have the same count. But when I then set the index and unstack (.set_index(['variable','k']).unstack(0)) I have almost twice as many rows. Weird. Shouldn't df1.shape[0] = n.shape[0]?

Comment: @Maccaroni123 if possible add some more data to the example. Works fine for the example data. may be another column or something

Comment: I found the error, had a column in the melt command twice. Thanks for the help!